# Dynamically Show/hide text based on radio button select

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p> Is the time stamp bold and italsized</p>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id='rb1' name="first" value="Message 1" class='q1'>
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" id='rb2' name="second" value="Message 2" class='q1'> 
<br>
<div class="answer">
</div>
<script>
$('.q1').change(function() {
    $('.answer').html($(this).val());
});

$('input').keydown(function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  switch (code) {
    case 89: // y
      $('#rb1').prop('checked', true);
      break;
    case 78: // n
      $('#rb2').prop('checked', true);
      break;
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code does exactly what i wanted but however, the text does not change dynamically when using shortcuts.The correct buttons are checked when either "y" or "n" is pressed, but the text don't change. They change only when selected with the mouse.where am i going wrong here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have 3 errors. First you got to change the keydown check event from input to any element inside the focus. Or you'll have to set the focus on the check box for the event to fire. In the below example I changed it to body.
Then, as @enucar said you have to call .change() to fire change event and change the names of the radios in order for one to unselect the other. If they don't have the same name you would have to unselect the other programmatically. Here is a working example:

```
<p> Is the time stamp bold and italsized</p>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id='rb1' name="q1group" value="Message 1" class='q1'>
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" id='rb2' name="q1group" value="Message 2" class='q1'> 
<br>
<div class="answer">
</div>
<script>
$('.q1').change(function() {
    $('.answer').html($(this).val());
});

$('body').keydown(function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    switch (code) {
    case 89: // y
      $('#rb1').prop('checked', true).change();
      break;
    case 78: // n
      $('#rb2').prop('checked', true).change();
      break;
  }
});
</script>
```

In JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/84ozw2as/6/

Answer (score 0):

Call `change()` function after changing the prop.

```
$('#rb1').prop('checked', true).change();
```

EDIT: Also, edit the name of radio buttons and give the same value.

```
<input type="radio" id='rb1' name="first" value="Message 1" class='q1'>
```

`<input type="radio" id='rb2' name="first" value="Message 2" class='q1'>`